# Tooltipster auto close after open

Tags: tooltipster

Im using tooltipster for call-outs. I need a solution it the user clicks, the call out opens but then it close after a certain time automaticly

My code:

```
$('.mgu-ekl-info').tooltipster({
            functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
                $.each($.tooltipster.instances(), function(i, instance){
                    instance.close();
                  });
            },
            functionReady: function(instance, helper){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(this).instance.close();               
                }, 3000);
            },
            contentCloning: true,
            trigger: 'click',
            'maxWidth': 280,
            'minHeight': 280,
            animation: 'grow',
            interactive: true,
            arrow: false,
            distance: -10,
            contentAsHTML: true,
            theme: 'tooltipster-shadow'
        });
```

Thanks for help.
Thomas

Comment: Something like the `timer` option?

Comment: Thanks, perfect!